# How to remove KeyCloak from Wildfly?

Tags: wildfly, keycloak, subsystem

I recently configured KeyCloak in my existing Wildfly server using the overlay installation:
bin/jboss-cli.sh --file=bin/keycloak-install.cli

I would like to remove it or disable it now. I'm pretty new to Wildfly. I think it should be the same way how to disable a subsystem?

Comment: Its one way only.  Best to scratch your wildfly.

Comment: You should be able to essentially reverse the CLI script replacing adds with removes. If you add a link to the CLI script or the contents of it I could probably help with that.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve it will be to open `standalone.xml` file in the `%JBossHome%>standalone>configuration` folder and remove/comment out the keycloak subsystem.

The subsystem configuration will look something like this

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:keycloak-server:1.1">
    <web-context>auth</web-context>
</subsystem>
```